# Can't augment react ComponentType type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm trying to augment the React `ComponentType` type for a compatibility layer I'm developing in my application, migrating from React 16 to 18.

The problem is, my augmented `ComponentType` is not being read. The default `ComponentType` defined in React types is being used instead. If I change the name of the exported type to `ComponentType2`, it works, so I know my types file is being included.

`src/types/react.d.ts`:

```
import * as React from "react";

type ComponentTypeCompat<P> = React.ComponentType<
  P & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }
>;

declare module "react" {
  type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentTypeCompat<P>; // <-- this is ignored
  type ComponentType2<P = {}> = ComponentTypeCompat<P>; // <-- this works
}
```

`src/components/OldComponent.tsx`

```
import { ComponentType } from "react";

export const OldComponent: ComponentType<{ value: number }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.value}
      {props.children} /* throws type error as children is missing on props */
    </div>
  );
};
```

`src/components/OldComponent2.tsx`

```
import { ComponentType2 } from "react";

export const OldComponent2: ComponentType2<{ value: number }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.value}
      {props.children} /* this works, reading the type as ReactNode as expected */
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a simple next.js reproduction repository here: https://github.com/felamaslen/augment-react

Comment: Did you find a solution, @Fela Maslen?